# React Native Android Absolute and zIndex Problem

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to make a component absolute in react native, but I can't get the result I want. When I change the order of the codes, the way it works changes.

**1st case**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
  
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
        zIndex: 20,
        elevation: 20,
      }}
    />
     <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#C6C6C6' }} />
  </View>
```

In this case, it happens as follows. Absolute component is not visible.

[image]

**2st case**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
  <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#C6C6C6' }} />
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
        zIndex: 20,
        elevation: 20,
      }}
    />
     
  </View>
```

In this case, the absolute component looks as follows.

[image]

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#C6C6C6' }} />
```

In case 1, it doesn't work if zIndex and elevation are set. Why does relocating the above code prevent it from being absolute?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Android that prevents zIndex from working properly outside the order of invocation.  Generally though, things come forward as they are rendered in the parent, so your code (correctly) gave the latter / lower component higher priority in case 2.

And it *is* correctly positioned absolutely, so I'm not sure what you meant by "Why does relocating the above code prevent it from being absolute?"

Note that this is in contrast to effect or absolute *in CSS* where all absolute elements are in a higher z grouping then their relative siblings.  RN has no such behavior. How something is positioned doesn't influence z order inherently.

(Also, no biggy, but you may want to fix the indentation in your examples as it can give the wrong impression re parent-child relationships at a casual glance.  It took me a few moments to see the correct hierarchy)